# sending HTTP requests obtained from WireShark

Tags: http, wireshark

I have an app controlling my AVR on a local network and I'm trying to embed some of the functionality into another app written by myself. I've started up WireShark and started controlling the volume, which shows up as:

```
GET /ctrl-int/1/setproperty?dmcp.device-volume=-15.750000 HTTP/1.1
```

I'm not totally up on this type of http control but i'd like to know if this is enough data to be able to send the same request via a browser or terminal etc.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the avr you can't realy tell. But you should be able to send the command via

```
avr-ip/ctrl-int/1/setproperty?dmcp.device-volume=-15.750000
```

in the browser or from you app. The ip should be in the wireshark logs as well.

If that works it was enough information.